# Laravel Eloquent: getting id field of joined tables in Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I need to get the id of a second table. I cannot avoid using a INNER JOIN since I have to ORDER the results by a column in the second table.

Here are my 2 tables

```
events
  id
  name
  ....
  date
 ...
myevents
  id
  meeventID
  meresults
  ....
```

To get my desired result I'm using the following

```
$finishedRaces = Myevent::where('meuserID', $user->id)
  ->join('events', 'myevents.meeventID', '=', 'events.id')
  ->whereRaw("`events`.`date` >= '$signupday' AND `events`.`date` <= '$today'")
  ->orderBy('events.date','desc')->get();
```

If I do

```
foreach($finishedRaces as $race){
  echo $race->id // this returns the id of the table events
}
```

I need the ids of both tables + all the values in both tables about 20 values in total.
Any idea on how to do that? 
I really would like to avoid using the `->select("columnname as someothername, ...")` unless I can only define the 2 id columns, if somehow possible.

Some requested additions

Here the relevant Models + functions

```
class Myevent extends Model{

    public function sportevent()
    {
            return $this->hasOne('Sportevent','id','meeventID');
    }

    public function athlete()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('User','id','meuserID');
    }

}
```

And here part of the Sportevent Model

```
class Sportevent extends Model{

    protected $table = 'events';
    // doesn't have a direct relation to Myevent model
}
```

And here the User Model with relevant functions

```
class User extends Model {

    public function myeventbydate($date){
        return $this->hasOne('Myevent','meuserID','id')
          ->join('events', 'myevents.meeventID', '=', 'events.id')
          ->where('events.date',$date)->get();
    }

    public function myevents($filter=""){
        if($filter==""){
            return Myevent::where('meuserID', $this->id)
              ->join('events', 'myevents.meeventID', '=', 'events.id')
              ->orderBy('events.date', 'desc')->first();    
        }else{
            return Myevent::where('meuserID', $this->id)
              ->join('events', 'myevents.meeventID', '=', 'events.id')
              ->where('events.country', $filter)
              ->orderBy('events.date', 'desc')->get();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the relationships in your models?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sometimes the solution is easier than you think. So basically I did the same as I would do in a standard SQL query:  `SELECT *, myevents.id AS me_id FROM ... '` Which then looks like this:

```
$finishedRaces = Myevent::where('meuserID', $user->id)
        ->join('events', 'myevents.meeventID', '=', 'events.id')
        ->whereRaw("`events`.`date` >= '$signupday' AND `events`.`date` <= '$today'")
        ->select('*','myevents.id as me_id')
        ->orderBy('events.date','desc')->get();
```

I was afraid that I had to specify every column in the `->select` statement, but it works well as this.

My ids are now accessible as

```
$race->me_id; // id of table myevents
$rade->id     // id of table events
```